Gatsby Re-fetching Unchanged Custom Post Types Continuously After Successful Gatsby Develop
I'm experiencing an issue where Gatsby continuously re-fetches a few unchanged posts from my WordPress custom post types after a successful gatsby develop build. This happens repeatedly, even though there are no updates to those posts.
What I've Tried:
Clearing the Gatsby cache and rebuilding the project.
Inspecting the WordPress API (WPGraphQL) for any triggers or differences between the unchanged posts and others.
All plugins and modules have been updated to the latest versions.
Steps to Reproduce:
Run gatsby develop.
Wait for the development server to build successfully.
Notice that Gatsby starts fetching some custom post type entries again, even though there are no changes to those posts.
Custom Post Types Affected:
quickreads
news
insights
inthenews
Observed Behavior:
After the build, Gatsby triggers re-fetching of a subset of posts from these custom post types. The posts remain unchanged on WordPress, yet Gatsby continuously tries to refetch them in subsequent builds.
CMS: WordPress
Front-end Framework: Gatsby
screenshot
